# How to redirect on the server side to override Angular.JS routing on a post?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-routing

I have created an ASP.NET MVC5 application which uses Angular.JS to control one of the pages. I am able to successfully post back to the ASP.NET controller using an `$http.post`, however, in the ASP.NET controller, if I try to `return View("NewPage")` or `return RedirectToAction("NewPage", "Home")`, it keeps me on my Angular.JS page.

Is there a way to override the client side Angular.JS routing, so that I can send the user to another view using the ASP.NET MVC controller?

Here's my Angular.JS post:

```
        $http.post("/calculator/post", vm.data)
            .then(function (response) {
                // Success

                // reset the data on a successful submit
                vm.data = {};
                vm.dataObjects = {};

            }, function (error) {
                // Failure
                vm.errorMessage = "Failed to find rates.";
            })
            .finally(function () {
                vm.isSubmitBusy = false;
            });
```

Here's my ASP.NET controller:

```
    //POST: Calculator
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post(CalcFormViewModel data)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           return View("NewPage");
        }

        TempData["Error"] = "An error occurred.";
        return RedirectToAction("Error");
    }
```

Using breakpoints in my ASP.NET controller, I can confirm that the `return View()` and `return RedirectToAction()` are being reached, however after a successful post, the page does not change in the browser.

Comment: do you really need ajax for the post?

Comment: I am new to Angular.JS, is there a better way to do the post? You're right, I don't need ajax because this is the last page of the angular form. How else can I do the post?

Comment: By submitting the form itself through browser default process.

Comment: Can I still pass in my JSON data object through a normal post?

Comment: would submit as standard form encoded data not json. Yes you could intercept and place json in a hidden field but would be just as simple to submit normal form ...assuming all data is contained in one form

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. My issue, is that my form has 10 different steps, each in a different Angular.JS view. I have a JSON data object that persists across the different steps. Then when I get to the last step, I want to submit it to my controller to save the data, and go to different section of my website. In the last step, I could create a bunch of hidden fields, but I'm not sure if that is the best way to do it? It's like 30 fields.

Comment: One way is could stringify the whole object into one hidden field. Then decode that string in hidden field to server side object. Or continue with `$http`, store data in session and send back url to use to do javascript redirect

Comment: Oh, that's a good idea. I didn't even think of that. If you want to type that up in an answer, I will mark it as correct. Because that correctly answers my question about how you can bypass Angular.JS when posting, in order to then use an ASP.NET controller to handle the routing.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're not asking the browser to navigate to a new resource. You're making a request with `XMLHttpRequest`. The response received by requests made with `XMLHttpRequest` can't affect the navigation of the browser. It would be down to you to interpret the response in the callback (`then` clause), and to force a page change by fiddling with `window.location.href` in your javascript.

Comment: Thank you for the response. What would be the best way to do this? Set a response status code and return a JSON string with the URL?